# How can I do a Reorganize Index Task on SQL Server 2000 using a script?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a Server that is running SQL Server 2000 and I need to add a Reorganize Index Task.  I haven't been able to find a way to create a Maintenance Plan so I am performing maintenance tasks using SQL Jobs.  One of the tasks I want to perform is to reorganize the index.  What sql code do I need to use to reorganize an index?  I've seen the code `ALTER INDEX ALL ON [TABLE]` but I need to reorganize the index on all tables in the database rather than just an individual table and I want to avoid a looping script if possible.

Comment: SQL Server is out of support. Rather than worrying about index maintenance, I'd focus on getting on a supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: @BrentOzar An update is on the horizon, but we can only move so quickly

Comment: Support ended four years ago, and it was telegraphed a decade in advance. Check your feet - you may have been trapped in a lava pool. ;-)